# How to add multiple sql_query binds at once?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am using diesel crate to comunicate with a PostgreSQL database.
I have a use case where i want to get data from table `preferences` into struct `Preferences`.
I want the output from databse to be filterd by tow fields in the table, to have a specific value in column `org_id` and to be in group of values in column `team_id` which i store their values in unknown length array, so i can't do
`sql_query(raw_sql).bind::<>().execute()`
because i don't know the number of
`bind::<>()`
then I tried to use [collect_binds](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/query_builder/trait.QueryFragment.html#method.collect_binds)
but it didn't work, itried to do the following

```
let mut filter = "".to_string();
let mut params:Vec<i64> = vec![];
let mut c =1;
let org_id = 10;

filter.push_str("(org_id=$1 AND team_id IN (");
params.push(org_id);
for team_id in get_needed_teams_id(){
     c = c +1;
     filter.push_str(&*format!("${}", c));
     params.push(team_id );
}
filter.push_str("))");


let raw_sql = format!("SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE {} ORDER BY user_id ASC, team_id ASC", filter);

let preferences:Vec<Preferences> = vec![];
let sql_res = sql_query(raw_sql).collect_binds(&mut param, &preferences);
```

Error returned :

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed: cannot satisfy `<_ as Backend>::BindCollector == Vec<i64>`
   --> src\db\preference_db.rs:146:38
    |
146 |     let sql_res = sql_query(raw_sql).collect_binds(&mut params, &preferences);
    |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot satisfy `<_ as Backend>::BindCollector == Vec<i64>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way in diesel to bind multiple parameters at once in a loop. [`collect_binds`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/query_builder/trait.QueryFragment.html#method.collect_binds) is entirely unconnected to this and exported by the `QueryFragment` trait. It can be used by the database connection implementation to receive a list of bind parameters for a given query, not to construct a query.